# C# Memory mapped files not working while debugging in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, memory-mapped-files

I am stuck with a strange behaviour within `Visual Studio 2015`.

I have one solution with two executable projects that read and write some data using a Memory Mapped File. The projects are set to run at different timings (Project1 first and then Project2 after some seconds of delay)

Project1 creates a Memory Mapped File with the following line:

```
MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmmf", 2000, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Project2 access the same MMF with:

```
MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmmf");
```

After that both applications start to share some vars / strings / structs.

If I start the solution from Visual Studio with "Start Without Debugging" button everything is working fine.

If I manually start the compiled executables (both release or debug) outside Visual Studio everything is working fine.

However, if I start the solution with the normal "START" button (both in release or debug mode) I receive a

> "FileNotFoundException"

from the second project.

I already tried with "GLOBAL" and "LOCAL" file namespace but things have not changed at all.

Has someone already run into this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try disabling the Great Satan of debugging differences in Visual Studio, the Visual Studio hosting process (under project properties -> Debug). Does that help? Also, as long as you're talking timing -- debugging adds a lot of time to startup, so make sure your processes aren't actually out of sync. *Also* also, make sure you are actually starting *both* processes when debugging (solution properties -> Startup Project -> Multiple startup projects).

Comment: Timing is the most obvious failure mode here, the OpenExisting() call executing before the CreateNew() call.  This will happen in Real Life as well, you need to make your code resilient to that.  Simple to do, catch the exception, sleep for a bit and try again.  Don't try forever.  You must also deal with one of the processes crashing and the other one being completely unaware of that.  Not simple to do.

Comment: @Jeoren, I tried your suggestions but unfortunately the problem still persist. Also the multiple startup projects are correctly setup.

Comment: @Hans, Yes i am aware of the timing. But unfortunately it doesn't change even if i wait for minutes. I have also a check that the createnew is run and finished before the open because the first application tries to w/r from the file before the second is started. I have a console output for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oddly enough it is working.
Since the multiple startup projects in visual studio doesn't allow to input a delay between the applications i put a Thread.sleep on top of the second application to simulate the loading time. (In the real environment these two applications will load with lot of delay between them). By removing the Sleep now everything is working fine also in Debug mode. I cannot explain to myself why it is working now.